# Reformat headers in Markdown files with sed fails

Tags: bash, sed, markdown

I tried to reformat headers in a markdown file with sed but somehow that doesn't seem to work.
Problem is that between the header # sign(s) and the header text needs to be one space, otherwise it is not correctly displayed.

So i tried to run several variations of sed commands to add this space after the # signs

```
sed -i "s/<expression>/\1 /g" test.md
```

<expression> being:

- `^\(\s*#+\)`
- `^\(\[#\]+\)`
- `^\(\[\#\]+\)`

-i should replace this inside the file, but when i review the file with `cat test.md`, the space is still missing. I even added a backslash in front of the space in the substitute, but no luck.

The content of test.md is the following example data:

```
#Heading 1
Some text
- a list entry
- another one
##Heading 2
text
##Heading 3
```

The command should result in e.g. line 1 `# Heading 1`

What am i missing?

Comment: `sed 's/^##*/& /'`

Comment: @jm666 That would also insert a space when the required space is already present in the ATX-style header. This can be prevented with [this expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64197802/2192488).

Comment: @SergeStroobandt yes, true. :) That was a quick comment 3 years ago, for helping the user fast - as usually they don't want modify the file when the space is already present...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to escape the plus sign, e.g.:

```
^\(\s*#\+\)
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to `pandoc` version 2, the newly required space in [ATX-style headers](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#atx-style-headings) can be automatically inserted as follows:

```
$ sed -i 's|\(^##*\)\([^# \.]\)|\1 \2|' test.md
```

#### Explanation

- `-i` edits the markdown file 'in place.'
- `s|…|…|` is a single substitution per line.
- Each `\(…\)` denotes a part in the search expression.
- `\1` and `\2` refer to the first, respectively, second part of the search expression.
- `^##*` means that the line should start `^` with one hash `#`, followed by zero or more hashes `#*`.
- The second search sequence part should start neither with a hash, space nor period `[^# \.]`.

#### Note

The last item in the explanation is **what differentiates this answer** from a more simple `sed -i 's|^##*|& |'`. The simpler `sed` command **would still insert a space even when there is already a space behind the starting hash sequence.**